# WPF can't access stackpanel which is inside of the grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't access a stackpanel inside the grid by x:name. Any idea why?

```
<Grid x:Name="main_holder">
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDatagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="10,40,10,66"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="ItemsPerPage" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="692,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">05</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>15</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>25</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button x:Name="previous" Content="Previous" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="827,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="22" Click="previous_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="next" Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="907,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="22" Click="next_Click"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="authSelector" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">ALL</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>For Authorisation</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Authorised</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Not Distributed</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Returned</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <StackPanel x:Name="pagination_stack" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" Margin="10,608,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="972">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,10,0"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I can access MyDatagrid in code behind but not the stackpanel.

Comment: Works for me in VS 2013, try posting your code-behind

Comment: I am using VS 2015. I just found that it is working if I place the stackpanel as the first element of the grid. But then authSelector, next, previous buttons not visible in the code beind. Thanks for you response.

Comment: Works fine for me with VS2015. .

Comment: I was pulling my hair because of this. Any idea why this wasn't work in the first place?

Comment: Do you get any error access it? or VS say don't have such control? Is restart VS solve problem?

Comment: Try use Grid.RowDefinitions and Grid.ColumnDefinitions to position your controls on grid. Worst you can do - place controls by settings margins.